# In thunderbird: mailing list with CC

Tags: thunderbird, mailing-lists

I have two sets of addressees that I send many emails to; one set is only CC'ed. What would be an efficient way to do it? I could set two mailing lists: one for the regular addressees and the other of the CC'ed and insert them to the right fields. Is there a way to have **one** list that knows which addressee should be CC'ed?

Answer (score 0):

A template message solved my problem. See http://kb.mozillazine.org/Message_templates